# How to remove elevation of MDDropDownItem in kivymd?

Tags: kivy-language

I want to center the dropdown item vertically on the appbar but the shadow looks annoying even after trying to match bg colors.
This is my kivy string text

```
MDDropDownItem:
      id: drop_item
      pos: appbar.pos[0] + dp(20), appbar.pos[1] + dp(30)
      text: "All Dose"
      font_size: "23sp"
      on_release: app.menu.open()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any kind of button to trigger the drop down menu. Then open the menu when it is clicked.
I use a MDFlatButton that has no shadow. You can customize it as you like.

```
    MDFlatButton:
        id: drop_item
        text: "All Dose"
        pos: appbar.pos[0] + dp(20), appbar.pos[1] + dp(30)
        font_size: "23sp"
        on_release: app.menu.open()
```

Comment: I got it working with TextButton